# Issue with Python code AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, debian, cherrypy

I'm trying to run the following code below and it keeps failing with the error from the title:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
>       response.body = self.handler()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 217, in **call**
>       self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 61, in **call**
>       return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>     File "web/800-53-server.py", line 79, in family
>       control_list.append('[%s-%d](/control?id=%s-%d) - %s' % (id, control, id, control, sc.title.title))
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

The code block it seems to error on is below:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def family(self, id="AC", format="html"):
    id = id.upper()
    family_control_count =  {"AC": 25, "AU": 16, "AT": 5, "CM": 11, "CP": 13, "IA": 11, "IR": 10, "MA": 6, "MP": 8,
        "PS": 8, "PE": 20, "PL": 9, "PM": 16, "RA": 6, "CA": 9, "SC": 44, "SI": 17, "SA": 22}
    families = {"AC": "Access Control", "AU": "Audit and Accountability", "AT": "Awareness and Training", "CM": "Configuration Management",
        "CP": "Contingency Planning", "IA": "Identification and Authentication", "IR": "Incident Response", "MA": "Maintenance",
        "MP": "Media Protection", "PS": "Personnel Security", "PE": "Physical and Environmental Protection", "PL": "Planning",
        "PM": "Program Management", "RA": "Risk Assessment", "CA": "Security Assessment and Authorization",
        "SC": "System and Communications Protection", "SI": "System and Information Integrity", "SA": "System and Services Acquisition"}

    control_list = []
    for control in range(1,family_control_count[id]+1):
        sc = SecControl("%s-%d" % (id, control))
        control_list.append('<div><a href="/control?id=%s-%d">%s-%d</a> - %s</div>' % (id, control, id, control, sc.title.title))

    return """<html>
```

More of the program below:

```
`#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, os.path
import sys
import random
import string
import json
import yaml
import cherrypy
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('web/templates'))

sys.path.append(os.path.join('lib'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join('data'))
from seccontrol import SecControl
from seccontrolviz import SecControlViz
from utilities import *


class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
          <head>
            <title>800-53 Controls</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css">
          </head>`
```

Comment: You Access to sc.title.title
It seems that maybe sc.  or. Sc.title are None.
Have you tried printing them?

Comment: I think that maybe because title is repeated twice?

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I took title out but it was still messing up. The strange thing is it works just fine on my macOS laptop but when I try to run it in Ubuntu or Debian with the same Python (2.7.x) version I get this issue

Comment: I'd assume the issue is that the `SecControl` function is returning `None` but without seeing what that function is, I can't help further.

Comment: It may be useful if you compare the python packages installed un both machines. Using pip freeze. Maybe it is a problem with different versions

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I used pip freeze on both systems and then used pip -r install requirements.txt . I have a git repo that I actually cloned that works just fine on Mac and not on ubuntu/debian.

Comment: Thanks Zev, ill post the SecControl as well

Comment: From a google search, I'm guessing that package is `GovReady`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `GovReady` (which I'm assuming this is using based on the import statements) relies on `xsltproc`. It is likely that you have it installed on your mac OS but not on the other machines. It needs to be installed with `sudo apt install xsltproc` or equivalent for your flavor of Linux because it is not a pip package.

Try running `xsltproc --stringparam controlnumber 'AC-1' control2json.xsl ../data/800-53-controls.xml` from your `800-53-server/lib` directory. The function you are calling is a wrapper for that command.

After installing that program, I get

```
{ "id": "AC-1",
  "title": "ACCESS CONTROL POLICY AND PROCEDURES",
...
}
```

Comment: I went down the rabbit hole and followed the function calls inside the package. It was a bit windy of a road but it paid off. I'm glad it worked for you!